# Why is Russia participating in the British royals' cult of personality?

Tags: united-kingdom, russian-federation

On Friday at 9pm GMT, the home page of TASS, the official press agency of the Russian Federation, showed about ten articles about the former British queen and two about the new king. I did not look into them, but except for one title mentioning that Putin would not attend the funeral, the tone of the other titles seemed positive, and they also cited many tributes.

Given all the [sanctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_sanctions_during_the_Russo-Ukrainian_War), the diplomatic wars, the accusations of [interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia%E2%80%93United_Kingdom_relations#2020s), the expulsion of [RT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RT_UK), and the threat of a new Cold War, I thought that their relations were not so good. Nonetheless, the Russians are participating in the international cult of personality surrounding the British royals. Why?

The
The mentioned articles linked on TASS' home page:

https://tass.com/world/1505481
https://tass.com/death-of-queen-elizabeth-ii
https://tass.com/world/1505489
https://tass.com/world/1505393
https://tass.com/world/1505327
https://tass.com/world/1505029
https://tass.com/world/1504921
https://tass.com/politics/1505319f
https://tass.com/world/1505163
https://tass.com/world/1505023

Comment: I don't see it as answerable, unless TASS explains why, which would typically be in an editorial/op-ed by a senior reporter.  However, I'll speculate that Russia wants to separate the British people from their current government's policy.  Given that the Queen/King have essentially **no** say on foreign policy, the sanctions were not a result of the queen's choices.  As such, anything else than respectul condolences, for a rather popular queen, would risk turning any British people sitting on the fence wrt sanctions more against Russia.  Like a certain POTUS dissing a long time senator's death

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The fact that the moderators remove all the answers to your comment, even if they don't say anything special, is a sign that the cult of personality is strictly enforced. But at least for now there is still my answer to the question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75313/what-made-queen-elizabeth-so-popular

Comment: The TASS website had several respectful stories about the death of King Abdullah of Saudi Arabia in 2015 with tributes from [Putin](https://tass.com/russia/772918), despite the country being a staunch American ally. There aren't many monarchs/equivalent leaders with the standing of Elizabeth so it's hard to get a clear comparison (no Japanese emperors or popes have died for a while).

Comment: @FluidCode since comments are getting removed on repeat here, let me point out I have nothing to do with it and I am not flagging anything.  the mods' reasons are their own.  nor did I VTC or DV this Q.  if is it re-opened, which I am also not voting on, I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *" if is it re-opened, which I am also not voting on, I'll repost my comment as an answer."* It would change little, or nothing. In the answer to the question I linked I already pointed out that your claim have little ground.

Answer (score 8):

Even if we discount the [fringe theories](https://t.me/istrkalkglk/3584) about Russia-UK relations:

- The main decision makers in Russia are quite old, and even to them the deceased British queen represents a constant for the whole duration of their political life. She was reigning even before Khruschev came to power and "saw it all".
- Whatever conflicts Russia now has with UK may be discounted as "these youth today" not knowing what they are doing.
- There is a strong Russian tradition of "saying good or nothing" about the deceased (unless it is a private conversation or something akin to an anonymous Telegram channel).
- Soviet TV was [quite fond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3H6YWt23I8) of British royalty in their coverage, as well.